# Clear contents of file without deletion

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm developing a sound recognition app on android and am using the MediaRecorder class as well as a tensorflow model. I create the audio file where I will be saving the recorder microphone audio in the onCreate method for the class

```
audioFile = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
audioFile += "/Recording.3gp";
```

And I set the output file of the mediaRecorder to this file in the startRecording class

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFile);
```

The issue im having is that I need to convert the recording into a series of MFCC values for the model to work, and the MFFC.java class im using requires that the recording be converted to a double array. I'm doing that like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(audioFile));

 int read;
 byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
 while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
 {
        out.write(buff, 0, read);
 }
  out.flush();
  byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
  int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
  double[] doubleArray = new double[bytes.length / times];
  for(int i=0;i<doubleArray.length;i++){
        doubleArray[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, i*times, times).getDouble();
  }
```

Which is how they said to do it on another stack overflow post. The issue with this is that the audio file im sending the recording(s) to just keeps adding the new recordings to previous ones. This is because I am recording the audio then passing it to my classifier method in a loop like so

```
while(true){
                try {
                    soundRecognition task = new soundRecognition();
                    task.execute();
                    sleep(1500);

                }
```

**Solutions I have tried**

I have tried to move the creation of the audio to the sound recognition class but I cant do that as it produces errors, specifically mediaRecorder start called in invalid state: 4.

I have tried to overwrite the file using a FileWriter and PrintWriter class, but this didnt work, im assuming because the file is and audio file.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to read a 3GP file as if it was an array of doubles?

Comment: Yes, The MFFC class I downloaded requires as such. It was found at https://github.com/chiachunfu/speech/blob/master/speechandroid/src/org/tensorflow/demo/mfcc/MFCC.java

Comment: Shouldn’t you be decompressing the 3GP file before, and then converting the PCM data to an array of doubles?

Comment: I can look into that, but I still would need a way to clear the file each time, right?